# Writing numeric value in a text document

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I'm new to VB.net and I managed to successfully write a text file. I'm attempting to store the entry of many numeric values in the text document. The code I wrote is:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Public Class set_time

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\MainRegistry")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\MainRegistry")
    End If
    If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\MainRegistry\MainRegistry.txt") = True Then

        System.IO.File.Delete("C:\MainRegistry\MainRegistry.txt")


    End If

    Dim MainRegistry As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\MainRegistry\MainRegistry.txt", True)
    MainRegistry.Write(monhour.Value + "," + monmin.Value)
    MainRegistry.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is I get an error at the `Write()` line: `Conversion from string "," to type 'Double' is not valid.`

Comment: any help as to what it does wrong or how it doesnt work as you'd like?  Are all those xxxHour|Min things different DTPs?

Comment: Provide a minimal complete verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can help you.

Comment: Ya, it gives me an error (Conversion from string "," to type 'Double' is not valid) I would like to know how to make the code work. Each xxxHour|Min is the name of a different numericupdown

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I've changed it to a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: This isn't a mcve. If you were a compiler and had to parse this one line, you would throw unknown declaration errors - it isn't **verifiable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

`MainRegistry.Write(monhour.Value + "," + monmin.Value)`

`monhour.Value` appears to be variable type of `double`, while you're trying to concatenate it with a string. Using the `ToString` function should help with this error.

`MainRegistry.Write(monhour.Value.ToString + "," + monmin.Value.ToString)`

[ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN